# Basin numbering according to Pfafstetter Method?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, hydrography

I would like to divide my basin into subbasins and numbers according to the Pfafstetter method.

Is there an easy way to implement this in Python using ArcPy?

Or are there some freely available Python packages or tools that could be used for preparing an ArcGIS toolbox to do this?

Comment: A starting point may be this paper from 2001 but it is not a subject that I have ever investigated: http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/proc01/professional/papers/pap1008/p1008.htm

Comment: I would say a good starting place is this paper that talks you through the steps. The DOI is:  [10.1016/S0022-1694(99)00011-6](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0022-1694(99)00011-6).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Pfafsteter method requires that your basin/drainage network is topologically correct.
Arcgis have several topologically rules that can help you with that!

Once you have the basin/drainage network you can implement it python with numpy. It has several functions to help find index and etc.
A simpler way is to use python list objects. They are a faster and use less memory to store your data while processing. It will require the creation of some functions to help your process.

I really do not know about freely arcgis/toolbox to apply the pfafstetter method. There is an interesting software that is being developed in postgres-postgis/python.

It would help if I knew specifically what you really want to do to try to explain a better solution.

Comment: I think this answer could be improved if you provided links or described the specific tools or functions in Python that could directly help the OP.